# How to generate same animation for every user in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I want to generate some random circles, which are moving in real time on the canvas, and make sure every user see the same thing.

But i have no clue. how to make sure it is the same? Do i need to store data？

I suppose it might need to use socket.io?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a string representation of the circles by converting them to a base64 (dataUri) string and simply broadcasting the string to users with socket.io.

Most of the node canvas libraries have this method (toDataUri) built in, so it should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: and also, i want those circles moving. So... i guess base64 is not that suitable?

Comment: @KarenPeng Node.js is server side only, there is no canvas library, or any kind of client side drawing library.

Comment: There is a canvas implementation for the server side: [node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas), but yes if you need animation (missed that bit) etc. you'll simply have to send drawing coordinates to the client and do all the drawing there.